# When refactoring a functional react component, should the functions be defined outside the component or inside it?

Tags: reactjs, refactoring

I have a React functional component inside which a function, that's triggered when a button is pressed, contains a lot of logic, like this

```
const reactFuncComp = () => {
    const doSomeLogic = () => {
    // A lot of logic
    }
    return (
      <button onClick={doSomeLogic}>Click</button>
    )
}
```

I want to refactor the logic inside `doSomeLogic` into well-defined functions with specific functionality, but I am not sure if I need to keep them inside the functional components, like this

```
const reactFuncComp = () => {
    const logicFunc1 = () => {/*...*/};
    const logicFunc2 = () => {/*...*/};
    const logicFunc3 = () => {/*...*/};
    const doSomeLogic = () => {
          logicFunc1();
          logicFunc2();
          logicFunc3();
    }
    return (
      <button onClick={doSomeLogic}>Click</button>
    )
}
```

or they can be defined outside the component, since they are only referenced from `doSomeLogic` like this

```
const logicFunc1 = () => {/*...*/};
const logicFunc2 = () => {/*...*/};
const logicFunc3 = () => {/*...*/};

const reactFuncComp = () => {
    const doSomeLogic = () => {
          logicFunc1();
          logicFunc2();
          logicFunc3();
    }
    return (
      <button onClick={doSomeLogic}>Click</button>
    )
}
```

Which one should I follow in this case?

Comment: It depends, in some cases, there might be things preventing them from being defined outside of the component, for example if they use hooks. Then they must be defined in the body. Otherwise I think it's fine to do both. One advantage if they're outside the body is that you don't have to define them as dependencies in dependency arrays since their identity will never change. On the other hand, you might want to use closures instead of passing contextual variables as arguments which you can't then.